# unable to access 'http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/', any alternative to compile properitary mibs

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

unable to access 'http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/', any alternative to compile proprietary mibs.
Is snmpLabs down ?

Need to compile mibs from .mib to .py format compatible with pysnmp

Answer (score 0):

As I am now taking over the PySNMP ecosystem, a new site `https://mibs.pysnmp.com` is created.

You'd better fully switch to `*-lextudio` packages at this time, as documented in https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/429

The old packages have `snmplabs.com` hard coded everywhere, so you cannot easily override all the URLs to `pysnmp.com`.